# NgRx Effects Unit Testing: Test catchError Case, Without Marbles

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to test a simple scenario, with the following Effect defined:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { TodosService } from '../services/todos.service';
import { getTodos, getTodosSuccess } from './todos.actions';

@Injectable()
export class TodosEffects {
  loadTodos$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(getTodos),
      mergeMap(() => this.todosService.getTodos()
        .pipe(
          map(todos => getTodosSuccess({ todoItems: todos })),
          catchError(() => EMPTY)
        )
      )
    )
  );

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private todosService: TodosService
  ) { }
}
```

In this scenario, I am **deliberately trying to get this working without Marbles**. That is, without `hot()` `cold()` and so on. The few examples I've found online covering this topic just use those, but I'm looking for a way to do this without that for now.

Here's what I have in my test class so far. The mocking of `TodosService`, first test of the happy path, mock actions setup, etc. all work as expected. The second test, the one where I'm basically trying to confirm that the `EMPTY` observable is generated by `catchError`, is where I'm struggling:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TodosService } from '@app/services/todos.service';
import { provideMockActions } from '@ngrx/effects/testing';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { EMPTY, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { TodoItem } from './todo-model';
import { getTodos, getTodosSuccess } from './todos.actions';
import { TodosEffects } from './todos.effects';

let actions$ = new Observable<Action>();

let effects: TodosEffects;
let todosServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<TodosService>;

describe('Todos Effects', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const todosServiceSpyObject = jasmine.createSpyObj('TodosService', ['getTodos']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        TodosEffects,
        provideMockActions(() => actions$),
        { provide: TodosService, useValue: todosServiceSpyObject }
      ]
    });

    effects = TestBed.inject(TodosEffects);
    todosServiceSpy = TestBed.inject<TodosService>(TodosService) as jasmine.SpyObj<TodosService>;
  });

  it('should return successful todo get action with service results', () => {
    actions$ = of(getTodos());
    const expectedTodos: TodoItem[] = [{} as TodoItem];
    todosServiceSpy.getTodos.and.returnValue(of(expectedTodos));
    const expectedAction = getTodosSuccess({ todoItems: expectedTodos });

    effects.loadTodos$.subscribe(result => {
      expect(result).toEqual(expectedAction);
    });
  });

  it('should return EMPTY observable I think?', () => {
    actions$ = of(getTodos());
    // todosServiceSpy.getTodos.and.throwError('');
    todosServiceSpy.getTodos.and.returnValue(throwError(''));
    const expected = EMPTY;

    effects.loadTodos$.subscribe();
    // TODO: What to expect / etc. here?
  });
});
```

The [NgRx Effects testing documentation is unfortunately quite lacking here](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/testing), as it only posts snippets and edge case testing scenarios for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `EMPTY` completes without emitting next or error, you could use that as the test

```js
let nextCount = 0
let errorCount = 0
let completeCount = 0

effects.loadTodos$.subscribe(
  () =>  {nextCount++},
  () =>  {errorCount++}
  () =>  {completeCount++}
)

// test that only completeCount === 1, and others are 0
expect(....).toEqual(...)
```